# The ideal $(x,y)$ is not a free $K[x,y]$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, modules, ideals

Given a field $K$ we have the polynomial ring $K[x,y]$ in $2$ variables, which is also a left module (over itself). How can we prove that the ideal $(x,y)$ is not a free module?

Comment: Sorry.  I meant the ideal <x,y>

Comment: Hint: any two elements are linearly dependent. So if it were free, it would be one-dimensional.

Comment: ...it would be of rank 1

Comment: @Chris: Very nice! So, in a domain, an ideal is free iff it's principal. (Of course, Mariano is right,
as usual...) --- [Related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/55067/660) (generalizing Chris's hint).

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: Dear @Chris: I suggest that you upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255814

Answer (score 13):

*This is a community wiki answer intended to remove this question from the unanswered queue.*

---

As Chris Eagle hinted in the comments, free ideals in a commutative domain can only be generated by a single element.

If $a,b$ were two elements of a basis of a free ideal in a commutative domain, then $ba+(-a)b=0$ would be a nontrivial $R$-combination of the two, but that is absurd if they are members of an $R$-basis.

So, $(x,y)$, which isn't principal, cannot be a free ideal of $K[x,y]$.