# Problem of monomorphism of rings

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ a ring, for each monomorphism $f:A^m \rightarrow A^n$, I don't know how to prove that $m\leq n$. I can't start the problem, I have no idea, help me please.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/106786/264

Comment: Presumably, you mean monomorphisms as $A$-modules?

Comment: If indeed monomorphisms of $A$ modules, are commutative rings intended? There is a noncommutative ring with $R^n\cong R^m$ as right $R$ modules for every pair of positive integers $m,n$.

Comment: I have a doubt, if f is a monomorphism then f is injective what means that for each element of $A^m$ has an only image in $A^n$, so if I suggest that m>n then some elements of $A^m$  have the same image in $A^n$. It is correct in this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Exterior power functors preserve monomorphisms of free modules. Use this to get an inequality involving binomial coefficients.