# $\mathbb{Z}^m\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}^n$ implies $m\le n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the question [$A^m\hookrightarrow A^n$ implies $m\leq n$ for a ring $A\neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106786/am-hookrightarrow-an-implies-m-leq-n-for-a-ring-a-neq-0), $A$ is a commutative ring. Is there a simpler proof for a domain, for example $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $K$ be its fractions field.
Assume the existence of a injective $A$-linear map $A^m\rightarrowtail A^n$.
Since $K$ is a [flat](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00H9) $A$-module, tensoring by $K$ (over $A$) preserves injectivity, hence we get a commutative diagram of $K$-linear maps

[image]

with a $K$-linear map $K^m\rightarrowtail K^n$ of $K$-vector spaces.
Note the $K$-linear isomorphism $A^n\otimes_A K\cong K^n$ which follows by induction from the canonical isomorphisms $A\otimes_A K\cong K$ and $(M\oplus N)\otimes K\cong (M\otimes K)\oplus (N\otimes K)$ explicited [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00CY).
Consequently,
$$m=\dim_KK^m\leq\dim_KK^n=n$$

Comment: Sorry, what does a "flat $A$-module" means?

Comment: Means that injectivity (or exactness) is preserved when tensored by a such module. I added a link in my answer in which you can find more details.

Comment: Ok perfect. I just dont know how to proof tha fact that $A^i\otimes K\simeq K^i$, but i will look for a solution. Thank you!

Comment: (if you know where I can find a proof, it would be nice!)

Comment: I added some details about the isomorphism $A^n\otimes K\cong K^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete proof for $\mathbb Z$.

Every additive map $\mathbb Z^m \to \mathbb Z^n$ extends to a $\mathbb Q$-linear map $\mathbb Q^m \to \mathbb Q^n$ of $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces.
If the map is injective, then its image has dimension $m$ and so $m\le n$.

When $D$ is a domain, this proof generalizes to $D$-linear maps $D^m \to D^n$ of $D$-modules, because they extend to $K$-linear maps $K^m \to K^n$ of $K$-vector spaces, where $K=Q(D)$.