# If there is a monomorphism between free $R$-modules $F \hookrightarrow G$, is the rank of $F$ necessarily less than or equal to the rank of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative, unital ring. Let $F = R^{(X)}$ and $G = R^{(Y)}$ be the free $R$-modules generated two arbitrary sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Assume there is a monomorphism $F \hookrightarrow G$. Does this imply that $|X| \leq |Y|$?

In the case where $X$ and $Y$ are finite, the answer is *yes* and several proofs can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106786/am-hookrightarrow-an-implies-m-leq-n-for-a-ring-a-neq-0) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-2-11). Notice that the solutions given in these threads firmly rely the finiteness condition, which leaves me wondering about the infinite case.

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3611502/137930), the cardinal of $R^{(X)}$ is $\max \left\{|R|,|X|\right\}$. It follows that if a counterexample exists then the following inequalites must be satisfied: $$\aleph_0 \leq |Y| < |X| \leq |R|$$

In particular, $|R| \geq \aleph_1$.

I feel quite out of my depth when it comes to searching for a counterexample because I don't know any $\aleph_1$-sized rings that are simple enough that it is possible to describe the relevant free modules over them... On the other hand, I really have no idea of how to approach a potential proof.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite case follows from the finite case.  Specifically, supposing $Y$ is infinite, for each finite subset $S\subseteq Y$, let $A_S\subseteq X$ be the set of basis elements of $F$ which map to elements of $G$ whose support is contained in $S$.  Note that our monomorphism $F\to G$ then restricts to a monomorphism $R^{(A_S)}\to R^S$, and thus $|A_S|\leq |S|$.  But every element of $X$ is in $A_S$ for some $S$.  Since $Y$ has $|Y|$ different finite subsets, and $A_S$ is finite for each one of them, it follows that $|X|\leq |Y|\cdot\aleph_0=|Y|$.