# How to prove this ideal is not locally free?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

> Let $I$ be an infinite set, $k$ a field, let $A=k^I$ (the product over the index set $I$), and let $\mathfrak a=k^{(I)}$ (the direct sum over the index set $I$). Then how can we prove $\mathfrak a$ is not a locally free module over $A$?

Since if it is locally free, then in some $D(f)$ we can prove $\mathfrak a_f=0$ or $\mathfrak a_f=A_f$. I want to prove $A_f \ncong a_f$ for any $f\in A$. But then I have no idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the contrary. Then $\mathfrak a$ is finite locally free since $\mathfrak a_f\subseteq A_f$. But finite locally free implies finite (see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00EO)). It is easily shown that $\mathfrak a$ is not finite.

Comment: Could you expand on your claim that $\mathfrak{a}_f$ is a finite $A_f$-module? I don't see why we should have that.

Comment: Free submodules of finite free modules are also finite.

Comment: A little searching found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106786/am-hookrightarrow-an-implies-m-leq-n-for-a-ring-a-neq-0) which I leave for others with the same question in the future.