# Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring. Then there does not exist a surjection from $A^m\rightarrow A^n$ for $ n>m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring. Then there does not exist a  surjective $A$-module homomorphism from $A^m\rightarrow A^n$ for $n>m$

Proof: Since $A$ is commutative it as a maximal ideal $M$. Therefore, suppose there exists surjection $f:A^m\rightarrow A^n$ where $n>m$. Therefore, $f\otimes Id:A^m\otimes A/M\rightarrow A^n\otimes A/M$ is surjective. This is a surjective linear map from a vector space of dimension $m$ to a vector space of dimension $n$. However, this is not possible.

Is this a valid proof? Proof verification.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106786/am-hookrightarrow-an-implies-m-leq-n-for-a-ring-a-neq-0

Comment: The existence of maximal ideals, however, requires using the axiom of choice in the form of Zorn's Lemma. Could the statement be proven in $ZF\neg{C}$ without using Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: If you are unsure if this is valid, then you suspect one of the steps (all two of them) is invalid. Is it the first step you are worried about? Because the second step is certainly valid.

Comment: I'm sorry which is the first step?

Comment: @JhonDoe The one where you conclude $f\otimes Id$ is the way you think it is.  (I agree, the argument is hardly even two steps.  The second step is just noting the contradiction...)

Comment: Actually never mind. This exact same argument is at the duplicate.

Comment: Oh I saw that it was surjective because every pure tensor has a pre-image. I was wondering about the dimensions of $A^m\otimes A/M$ but I realized that  $A\otimes A/M$ is isomorphic to $A/M$ which has dimension 1.