# Exercise 2.11 Atiyah-Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is part of the exercise, I'm stuck with it.

$A$ is a commutative ring with unit.

1) Suppose we have an homomorphism $\phi : A^{m} \to A^{n}$ surjective. Is true that $m \geq n $ ?

2) Suppose we have an homomorphism $\phi : A^{m} \to A^{n}$ injective. Is true that $m \leq n $ ?

Comment: Do you know how to do the exercise if $A^m$ and $A^n$ are $k$-vector spaces?

Comment: @rghthndsd: yes

Comment: Follow the same methodology here. Namely for (1) choose elements of the domain that map to $(1, 0, 0, ...)$, (0, 1, 0, ...)$, etc. Show that they are independent. This depends on knowing that the rank of a free module is well-defined - is this ok?

Comment: Duplicate of 1) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20178/given-a-commutative-ring-r-and-an-epimorphism-rm-to-rn-is-then-m-geq-n; 2) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106786/am-hookrightarrow-an-implies-m-leq-n-for-a-ring-a-neq-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:** The answer to both is yes.  For (1) tensor by the residue field of a maximal ideal.

For (2) assume, by way of contradiction, that $m > n$.  Consider $A^n \subseteq A^m$ and consider $\phi\colon A^m \to A^m$ as a map into $A^m$.  Let $\pi\colon A^m \to A^m$ be a projection map such that $\pi\phi = 0$.  Now use Proposition 2.4 on $\phi$ so show it satisfies some relation.  Then use $\pi$ and the injectivity of $\phi$ to reduce that relation to $\phi = 0$.

Comment: can you specify your argument about Proposition $2.4$ ?

Comment: To start with, do you know what 2.4 gives you?