# Basic question about modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I suppose that this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find anything precise online. Let $R$ be a ring, and take an $R$-module $M$; assume also that $M$ is finitely generated, by a set of cardinality $n$. How do I prove that, if I take $m$ elements of $M$, with $m>n$, they can't be linearly independent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linearly independent elements are less than generators in a module.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258071/linearly-independent-elements-are-less-than-generators-in-a-module)